# why console.log doesn't show values of properties added by PROTOTYPES in javascript when whole object is printed?

Tags: javascript

I know Prototype is used to add properties or methods and JavaScript objects inherit their properties and methods from their prototype.

```
var  Person=function (name) {

this.Fname=name;
this.health=100;

};
//create object of Person
var Mateen=new Person("Mateen");
var Fariza=new Person("Fariza");


console.log(Mateen);
console.log(Fariza);

//output { Fname: 'Mateen', health: 100 }
         { Fname: 'Fariza', health: 100 }

//Adding method by prototype
Person.prototype.attack=function  attack(target) {
target.health-=2;
}

Fariza.attack(Mateen);

console.log(Mateen);
console.log(Fariza);

//output: { Fname: 'Mateen', health: 98 }
          { Fname: 'Fariza', health: 100 }

//adding proterty by prototype
Person.prototype.level=1;

console.log(Mateen);
//output: { Fname: 'Mateen', health: 98 }
```

In last output why it doesn't show level when whole object is printed. It do shows when console.log(Mateen.level) is used.

Comment: Because there's a metric ton of stuff on the prototype chain of each object, and printing it all would be less than helpful.

Comment: but shouldn't it just be showing regardless of being it helpful or not.

Comment: That depends on the browser. There's no official definition of what `console.log` is supposed to do. Some browsers allow you to expand and dig into the prototype chain interactively; others don't.

Comment: Right, actually I tried on intelliJ IDEA ide and google chrome browser both didn't show, so I thought if there is special reason. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: try console.dir, instead of console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this can depend on the browser but in **Chrome** you can view it by expanding the `__proto__`-object directly in the console.

[image: Chrome]

In **Firefox** you can click on the output, and get a similar output as chrome to the right/bottom.

[image: Firefix]

**Safari** is similar to Chrome

[image: Safari]

Unfortunately I can't verify IE/Edge

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT: TL;DR This is due to inheritance & the prototype chain. The console.doesn't log inherited properties but may log the prototype which can be expanded to find these.)

You are modifying the prototype object of your original `Person` function, not the instances you have created. When you console log the instances, you are just logging the properties of that actual object, not those inherited fro prototypes.
If you access the `level` property of `Mateen` as in your example, Javascript looks for the property on the object & if not found, looks down the prototype chain & finds it there

```
console.log(Mateen.level)   // 1 : Value is actually coming from Mateen.__proto__.level
```

If you were to explicitly add the property to `Mateen` then it would show up in your console.log, whereas `Fariza` would still inherit it from the Prototype.

```
Mateen.level = 10;
console.log(Mateen);   // { Fname: 'Mateen', health: 100, level: 10 }

console.log(Fariza);   // { Fname: 'Mateen', health: 100}
console.log(Fariza.level)   // 1 : Taken from Fariza.__proto__.level
```