# updating object does not show the new property

Tags: javascript

the code in the example works fine but in my codes it doesn't

I`m trying to update object with a new property

```
 const overrides = {paths:{"/":{}}}
 const aItems = [{endpoint:"/test"}]
 const mockOverrides = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(overrides));

 aItems.forEach(({endpoint}) => {
    if (!mockOverrides.paths[endpoint]) {
      mockOverrides.paths[endpoint] = {};
    }
    console.log(mockOverrides); // result {paths:{"/":{}}} expected {paths:{"/":{}, "/test":{}}}
    console.log(mockOverrides.paths[endpoint]) // result is  {}  twice
})
```

as you can see the property is not displayed in the output
but is somehow exist why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

After adding a `)` to the end of the `foreach` method, it appears to be working fine:

```js
 const overrides = {paths:{"/":{}}}
 const aItems = [{endpoint:"/test"}]
 const mockOverrides = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(overrides));

 aItems.forEach(({endpoint}) => {
    if (!mockOverrides.paths[endpoint]) {
      mockOverrides.paths[endpoint] = {};
    }
    console.log(mockOverrides); // result {paths:{"/":{}}} expected {paths:{"/":{}, "/test":{}}}
    console.log(mockOverrides.paths[endpoint]) // result is  {}  twice
});
```

Comment: I said the value does not appear in the new object 
here I just forget to add the `)` but why in my code it doesn't work

Comment: That means that this code in isolation is ok. If you are able to create a test case where it doesn't work, then we can have a look at why that might be. Maybe there is other code which is affecting this in some way. You could try moving this code to its own function to better separate it, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I wrote that but it was deleted. You were missing the `)`. Other than that the code is fine.

Comment: I know here its fine but in my code it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the new property was set to `__proto__` of mockOverrides.paths

> [why console.log doesn't show values of properties added by PROTOTYPES in javascript when whole object is printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716249/why-console-log-doesnt-show-values-of-properties-added-by-prototypes-in-javascr)

You can reproduce it by run below code on chrome console (also get from the quote above)

```
var  Person=function (name) {
  this.Fname=name;
  this.health=100;
};

var Mateen=new Person("Mateen");

console.log(Mateen);
// result: { Fname: 'Mateen', health: 100 }
Person.prototype.level=1;

console.log(Mateen);
// result: { Fname: 'Mateen', health: 100 }
console.log(Mateen.level);
// result: 1
```